# Controls suddenly disappeared on form designer

Tags: vb.net

I just added a new item to a toolstrip menu in my main form and all of a sudden all of my controls located on this form disappeared!

It's really strange as I didn't get any error or anything similar, I can also run the application normally but the controls are missing on my main form only.

I tried cleaning/rebuilding my solution and restarting Visual Studio 2012 but nothing seems to work.

This is what my main form looks like now:
[image: My Main Form]

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look inside the designer code to see if they are still there

Comment: They are only declared. For example btnBuild exists in the designer code as "Friend WithEvents btnBuild As Cody.CodyButton" only.

Comment: It will probably be easier to delete them from there and rebuild the form

Comment: Hmm. Yes, this seems to be the only solution. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using VS 2012?  This past week I had several items disappear from a menu and toolstrip.  They were there, in the designer, but not being added to their container.

Comment: If you have some "nasty nesting", it happens sometimes. Designer has hard time understand how to build hierarchies. I would do it careful, slow adding some controls. I've definitely seen this. Sometimes I had just go to source control and do "get latest", and start over. I think, it may happen if you cut/copy-paste controls

Comment: @dbasnett yes I'm using VS 2012 and I'm facing the same issue as you.

Comment: @T.S. I added the controls straight from the toolbox.
I placed the controls from scratch deleting the old ones from the designer code and it seems to be fine until now.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since you did not posted any codes so let me assume the 'Disappeared Controls' are :

```
Friend WithEvents txtMDF As TextBox
Friend WithEvents txtLDF As TextBox
Friend WithEvents btnMDF As Button
Friend WithEvents btnLDF As Button
Friend WithEvents Label1 As Label
Friend WithEvents Label2 As Label
```

> Where txtMDF, btnMDF, Label1, etc all are controls...

**Step 1** - We have to go to the 'Designer Code'

Now from the Designer, Right-click and select 'View Code (F7)' then from the drop-down menu at top which contains the list of Controls select 'FormName' (The first item from the list e.g. above 'FormName Events') and then from the next drop-down menu select 'Initialize Component'

**Step 2** - Add the following code under `Private Sub InitializeComponent()`

`Me.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {txtMDF, txtLDF, btnMDF, btnLDF, Label1, Label2})`

**Step 3** - Voila! Done.

Now 'Save All' and return to the FromName Designer and you will get back all of your Controls as before.

> Note: Please mark this answer as 'Answer'  if it works because it will allow others to try the answer with little more confident! :D
>
> You can follow [Microsoft Support Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1765830) for this after encountering other forums posts about the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the same issue after accidentally double clicking a control. It created an event function in the form code and then created a call to that function somewhere else. In my case, I deleted the function from the form code, but the program was still trying to call that function. I merely had to delete the call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).