# Windows Form. Toolbox items disappeared from design view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Using C# with Windows Forms in Visual Studio. After adding a menu item, all the toolbox items disappeared from the form. The items are still there and can see their properties.

I've tried excluding and including again. I've tried changing the display settings on my computer from 100% to 150% back to 100%.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Give the below link a shot [Possibly already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415685/controls-suddenly-disappeared-on-form-designer)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that before posting.

Comment: Click on one and it should hilight its location, if it's behind one of those FlowLayoutPanels you have going on. Also looking at the designer might show hints to what container holds the controls.

Comment: Nothing is getting highlighted when I select it on the properties drop down. I looked in the designer and there are a lot of "SuspendLayout()" functions. Could this be it?

Comment: There is also this line, is this the container? "this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();"

Comment: Do they come back if you remove the menu items?

Comment: No. I've had to create another form and set it up again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post but I did not see the correct answer. Not sure of the reason but you can recover the toolbox items by going to there property value and most likely one or both values will be in negative space, to get them back delete the negative value and it should put them back on your form... i.e if  the property location value is for example "-340, -630" change to "340, -630". That should then relocate your items back to your form

Answer (score 0):

there has to be a panel you're using , maybe you're item's are under the panel try moving the panel see if that works

Comment: I can't select any of the panels

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in vs2022 by going to search at the top and entering "toolbox".

Alternatively it's under the view menu: view > toolbox